# Rs and Rd in series in MOSFET circuit?

Tags: mosfet, current, nmos

[image]

Can we consider Rs and Rd to be in series? That is, is the equation ID = (Vdd)/(Rd+Rs) correct?

What is confusing me is that they have the same current, but there's a voltage drop across the drain-source.

Comment: If Rds is significant you must add it to your equation.

Comment: Even if the MOSFET is in saturation?

Comment: Depending on the device characteristics and current, yes.  Even MOSFETs turned on hard have some non-zero resistance.

Comment: @HaniAlJamalJr., The "saturation" mode for a MOSFET is not equivalent to the "saturation" mode for a BJT. It's more like the forward active mode of the BJT. If your MOSFET is in saturation, then Id will be determined more by \$V_{gs}\$ than by Rd or Rs. (Although of course Rs will affect \$V_{gs}\$).